# Allow multiple consumer for the same queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

Let's say I have a queue `FILE_DATA`. The main process will read from it and does whatever it has to do, but at the same time I want to have another listener to the same queue for auditing purposes.

Does ActiveMQ 5.x support such things?

I am using SpringBoot.

Comment: Which ActiveMQ broker are you using ("classic" 5.x or Artemis)?  What protocol is the client using?

Comment: Also, are you saying you want the two  (i.e. the "main" and the "audit") consumers to each get a copy the same messages (e.g. publish/subscribe semantics)?

Comment: I am using classic version .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want something along the lines of a [Mirrored Queue](http://activemq.apache.org/mirrored-queues.html) to be able to subscribe a consumer to and see what data is passing through the Queue.  ActiveMQ supports many such features so a look through the documentation would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks this will definately fit in.